# Using jQuery.getJSON in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, jsonp

I need to do a cross-domain request in a chrome extension. I know I can it via [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) but I'd rather stick to just jQuery idioms (so my javascript can also work as a `<script src="">`).

I do the normal:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

but in the error console I see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonp1271044791817 is not defined
```

Is jQuery not inserting the callback function correctly into the document? What can I do to make this work?

(If I paste the code into a chrome console, it works fine, but if I put it as the page.js in an extension is when the problem appears.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alas, none of these worked, so I ended up doing the communication via the background.html.

background.html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script>
function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
  if (request.action == 'getJSON') {
    $.getJSON(request.url, callback);
  }
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
</script>
```

javascripts/page.js

```
chrome_getJSON = function(url, callback) {
  console.log("sending RPC");
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'getJSON',url:url}, callback);
}

$(function(){
  // use chrome_getJSON instead of $.getJSON
});
```

Comment: When I do this, I got this error: `Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: What do I include inside the function if I wanted to display an element from the JSON Array?

Answer (score 3):

If you specify "api.flickr.com" in your [manifest.json](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) file you will not need to use the JSONP callback, script injection style of cross domain request.

For example:

```
"permissions": ["http://api.flickr.com"],
```

This should work beautifully in you code.  I would remove the querystring parameter "&jsoncallback" as there is no JSONP work needed.

The reason why your current code is not working is your code is injecting into pages DOM, content scripts have access to the DOM but no access to javascript context, so there is no method to call on callback.

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone viewing.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Because of 
http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy

Answer (score 2):

My impressions it that this fails because the jQuery callback function is being created within the 'isolated world' of the Chrome extension and is inaccessible when the response comes back:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment

I'm using Prototype and jQuery for various reasons, but my quick fix should be easy to parse:

```
// Add the callback function to the page
s = new Element('script').update("function boom(e){console.log(e);}");
$$('body')[0].insert(s);

// Tell jQuery which method to call in the response
function shrink_link(oldLink, callback){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://api.awe.sm/url.json",
        data: {
            v: 3,
            url: oldLink,
            key: "5c8b1a212434c2153c2f2c2f2c765a36140add243bf6eae876345f8fd11045d9",
            tool: "mKU7uN",
            channel: "twitter"
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: callback
    });
}

// And make it so.
shrink_link('http://www.google.com', "boom");
```

Alternatively you can try using the extension XHR capability:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.example.com/data.json", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: this worked for me for calling JSONP within a TamperMonkey script.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is a little off. There's no need for the `callback(` bit. This works flawlessly. Tested in the javascript console of Chrome on this StackOverflow page (which includes jQuery):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Fixed the syntax (copy and paste sorry). It works fine in the console, but not when run as the `page.js` of an extension

Comment: Is `page.js` a content script?

Comment: Just an FYI, he was talking about CHROME EXTENSIONS. Not in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As many of you will know, Google Chrome doesn't support any of the handy GM_ functions at the moment.

As such, it is **impossible** to do cross site AJAX requests due to various sandbox restrictions (even using great tools like [James Padolsey's Cross Domain Request Script](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/))

I needed a way for users to know when my Greasemonkey script had been updated in Chrome (since Chrome doesn't do that either...). I came up with a solution which is documented here (and in use in my [Lighthouse++](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/81657) script) and worth a read for those of you wanting to version check your scripts:

http://blog.bandit.co.nz/post/1048347342/version-check-chrome-greasemonkey-script