# How to use WhateverOrigin to circumvent same-domain policy

Tags: javascript

I went to whateverorigin.com to generate this line of javascript:

```
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' +
  encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + 
  '&callback=?', function(data){ alert(data.contents); });
```

I put that in place of the `XMLHttpRequest` I was using before, and nothing happens. Chrome says I have an Uncaught Reference Error: `jQuery110201568311753217131_1395117728011` is not defined. I must not be setting everything up right, what else do I need to do besides put that line with the relevant url in my JavaScript?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @PatrickEvans jQuery version 1.10.2

Comment: @aquemini : for same domain you don't need to use '&callback=?', even though if use that, you must resend same callback with your response

Comment: Interestingly, you can run that code on page and it works! :-)

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that recreates your problem, as http://jsfiddle.net/968TS/ the basic setup in this fiddle shows it working

Comment: @PatrickEvans http://jsfiddle.net/968TS/4/ i think that captures it

Comment: @aquemini - this variation seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HPTFm/.  You have to include "callback=?" with `$.getJSON()` for it to know that you want to use JSONP which is required for cross origin.

Comment: @jfriend00 that does work in fiddle, but not in the browser. when i add "callback=?" back in, i get the uncaught reference error i mentioned in the original post. any reason that could be?

Comment: @aquemini - then something else (that you haven't disclosed to us) is wrong with your regular page.  jQuery knows how to process that request if you set it up right.

Comment: @jfriend00 here's the fiddle with my exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/HPTFm/7/...same problem, works in fiddle, not in my chrome extension. i even put an "alert(team)" right before the call to .getJSON and that works fine in Chrome

Comment: Hmmm, you didn't say until just now that this is a Chrome extension.  I wonder what is different about that environment?  Perhaps it has a different global variable space and thus the JSONP callback can't find the global function it's supposed to call?

Comment: Yep, that was it.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Chrome extension has it's own sandboxed global variables and thus the global callback function that a JSONP request uses doesn't work when made from a Chrome extension.

See [JSONP request in chrome extension, callback function doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495825/jsonp-request-in-chrome-extension-callback-function-doesnt-exist) and [JSONP communication in a Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977720/jsonp-communication-in-a-google-chrome-extension) and [Using jQuery.getJSON in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619827/using-jquery-getjson-in-chrome-extension) for further details.  This question is probably a dup of that one.

If you search Google for "JSONP Chrome Extension", you find many discussions of this issue with several different resolutions depending upon the exact circumstances.

Comment: @aquemini - yeah, the missing piece of info was that you're in a Chrome Extension.  The Google search was quite simple once we knew that to be the relevant difference.